# Computerguess remains the same in Javascript Random Letter Game

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a random letter game where the computer guesses a random letter and the user has to try and solve it. I want the computer to save the guess for multiple turns, but chooses a new number upon each .keyup I want the letter to change upon the user guessing the correct letter, but it stays "x" regardless.  This is my first post and i'm new to coding so dont be jerks please.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>The Psychic Game</title>



</head>
<body>

<h1>The Psychic Game</h1>

<div id="game">
<p>Guess what letter I'm thinking of</p>

<p>Wins: </p>
<p>Losses: </p>
<p>Guesses: 9</p>
<p>Your Guess So far: </p>


  <script type="text/javascript">



 var options = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]; 
var wins= 0;
var losses= 0;
var turns= 9;
var guess="";





document.onkeyup = function(event) {
var computerGuess = options[Math.floor(Math.random()*options.length)];

console.log(computerGuess);



var userguess = event.key;





if (userguess == computerGuess) {
  wins++;
  turns = 9; 
  guess = ""; 
}

else if(userguess !== computerGuess) {
 turns--;
 guess += userguess + ", ";}







  if (turns ==0) {
    losses++;
    turns= 9;
    guess="";



}




var html = "<p>Guess what letter I'm thinking of</p>" + 
  "<p>wins: " + wins + "</p>" +
  "<p>losses: " + losses + "</p>" +
  "<p>turns: " + turns + "</p>"+
  "<p>Your Guess So Far: " + guess + "</p>";

document.querySelector('#game').innerHTML = html;









}




  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Check the console. The computer guess is different every time.

Comment: please, http://img.picturequotes.com/2/47/46731/always-code-as-if-the-guy-who-ends-up-maintaining-your-code-will-be-a-violent-psychopath-who-knows-quote-1.jpg

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fnvdu3mf/ There it is in a fiddle exactly as you wrote it and working as expected

Comment: I also included the "computerGuess = options[Math.floor(Math.random()*options.length)];" at the last if statement so that when turns =0 the computer guess changes to a new letter when the turns revert back to 9

Answer (score 0):

Working fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/umn82x4b/

Added initialization condition

```
var options = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]; 
var wins= 0;
var losses= 0;
var turns= 9;
var guess="";



var computerGuess;
var intialized=true;
document.onkeyup = function(event) {
debugger
if(intialized){
computerGuess = options[Math.floor(Math.random()*options.length)];
intialized=false;
}
alert(computerGuess);


var userguess = event.key;
if (userguess == computerGuess) {
computerGuess = options[Math.floor(Math.random()*options.length)];
  intialized=true;
  wins++;
  turns = 9; 
  guess = ""; 
}

else if(userguess !== computerGuess) {
 turns--;
 guess += userguess + ", ";}







  if (turns ==0) {
    losses++;
    turns= 9;
    guess="";



}




var html = "<p>Guess what letter I'm thinking of</p>" + 
  "<p>wins: " + wins + "</p>" +
  "<p>losses: " + losses + "</p>" +
  "<p>turns: " + turns + "</p>"+
  "<p>Your Guess So Far: " + guess + "</p>";

document.querySelector('#game').innerHTML = html;









}
```